# How to concatenate the success message in magento 2 in cart?

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, success-message

I created a module to alter the cart message.

> app\code\Eight25media\Changemsg\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add">
    <observer name="updatemessage" instance="Eight25media\Changemsg\Observer\UpdateCartSuccessMessage" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app\code\Eight25media\Changemsg\Observer\UpdateCartSuccessMessage.php

```
<?php

namespace Eight25media\Changemsg\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class UpdateCartSuccessMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface */
protected $messageManager;

/** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
protected $url;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
) {
    $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages();
    $message = $messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText();

    $message = str_replace(' shopping', '', $message);
     $st = strpos($message, "don");
    $st1 = strpos($message, "have");
    if ($st !== false && $st1 !== false) {
        $cartLink = 'You can request a quote, continue shopping, or view your cart <a href="'. $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart') .'">here</a>';
    }else{
        $cartLink = 'You can continue shopping or view your cart <a href="'. $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart') .'">here</a>';
    }

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message . '  ' . $cartLink);
}
}
```

If i remove **true** in this line `$messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);` i am getting 3 messages like this image.where success message added in 2 different section. if i add **true** in this line `$messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);` i am getting the last latest last message only.

Before come to my last message i want to add the previous message also to the final message.How can i concatenate this message in this observer file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you need here, but in case you want to modify the last message you can try this.

```
$messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages();
$lastMessage = $messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage();
if ($lastMessage) {
    $messageText = $lastMessage->getText();
    $messageText = modify here your message as you want.
    $lastMessage->setText($messageText);
}
```

Calling `$this->messageManager->addSuccess` will always add a new message to the session.